# Count occurrence of each value inside an array for each document with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a problem with MongoDB that I am not able to solve...
I have a list of documents and each document contains an array of String called *"types"*.

Here an example:

```
{
    "_id" : 19841,
    "types" : [ 
        "A", 
        "A", 
        "B", 
        "C"
    ],
    "other_fields" : 1,


/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 11212,
    "types" : [ 
        "A", 
        "B"
    ],
    "other fields" : 1,

}

....
```

I would like to add, inside each document, an object (or even another data structure) that contains the number of occurrences of each element contained inside the array "types".

I would like to have a result like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 19841,
    "types" : [ 
        "A", 
        "A", 
        "B", 
        "C"
    ],

  "occurences" : {
        "A" : [ 
            "2"
        ],
        "B" : [ 
            "1"
        ],
        "C" : [ 
            "1"
        ]}

    "other_fields" : 1,


/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 11212,
    "types" : [ 
        "A", 
        "B"
    ],
  "occurences" : {
        "A" : [ 
            "1"
        ],
        "B" : [ 
            "1"
        ],
        }
    "other fields" : 1,

}
```

....

I added a field named *"occurrences"* that contains what I want.

I am trying with several queries but I am not able to achieve the expected result...

Any suggestions? Thanks!